# After how long does a Discord Bot time out? (discord.js)

Tags: python, discord, discord.js

Im making a discord bot and I'm writing a script in python that will execute the bot for me as soon as it times out. So I'm wondering after how long the bot times out so the script can execute the bot again.

This is the python script:

```
import os
import time

pid = os.getpid()

os.system('cls')
print('Process id: ' + str(pid))
File = input('In what folder is your bot file located? ')
runFile = input('What file is used to run the bot?\nExample \'index.js\', \'main.js\' or \'bot.js\' ')

os.chdir(str(File))
time.sleep(1)
print('Bot turning online 24/7...')
os.system('node ' + str(runFile))
time.sleep(1)
```

I'm going to make it so it loops and executes the bot again and again. As I said, after how long does a bot time out?

Comment: The bot shouldn't disconnect or time out on it's own. This may be caused by your internet connection.

Comment: Thanks @Piecuu I asked my dad, and he said our network disconnects from it's DNS server between 0:00 and 6:30. This can be one of the problems why it disconnects and times out.

Comment: I don't know much about discord.js but discord.py will automatically try to reconnect your bot for you. I assume it is the same with discord.js.

Comment: I'm guessing this doesn't have anything to do with discord.py? I'm not sure why that tag was edited in, but you should rollback that edit.

Comment: @TheFungusAmongUs This is not discord.py, this is discord.js. I'm writing a script in Python though to execute the bot after it has timed out. Btw my bot literally just timed out.

Comment: @Piecuu Read comment above ˆˆˆ

Comment: @LeoTurlock Yep, but it looks like someone mistakingly editted that tag in. You should [edit] to roll it back if it doesn't apply to your question